# Filtering a stream if the previous filter resulted in an empty stream JAVA

Tags: java, spring-boot, lambda, logic, refactoring

I have several hours trying to find an easier solution, but I have not been able to come up with an optimal answer.

My problem is that I have two `Set<String>` and a `List<>` I must apply a first filter to the list<> according to a set, in case the result is empty or has only 1 element, I must filter again the `List<>` with the missing `Set<String>`.

I have this logic and, although it works, it seems to me a little ugly.

```
  private static final Set<String> ALLOWED_PATH =
      Set.of("/anto", "chachi");
  private static final Set<String> SECOD_ALLOWED_PATH =
      Set.of("/jose", "chuchu");


  public void valid(final List<itemObject> itemList) {

    List<itemObject> itemFiltered = filterPath(itemList, ALLOWED_PATH);

    if (itemFiltered.size() < 2) {
      itemFiltered = filterPath(itemList, SECOND_ALLOWED_PATH);
    }

    //Continue code
  }


  private List<itemObject> filterPath(
      final List<itemObject> itemList, final Set<String> allowedPath) {

    return itemList
        .stream()
        .filter(
            item ->
                allowedPath
                    .stream()
                    .anyMatch(
                        path ->
                            item.getPath().contains(path) && item.getValue().equals(Boolean.TRUE)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

In my example, it works but I don't like the idea of having to check if the size of the list is less than 2 to know that it has not found the 2 path of the first one and I must do the second filter.

I am not an expert in lambda, is there any way to make it more optimal?

Thanks!

Comment: `item.getValue().equals(Boolean.TRUE)` should be equivalent to `item.getValue()`.

Comment: I do not fully understand the business use case. That being said, the fact that we have to do a second, conditional, filtering suggests to met hat this isn't something well-suited for a streamified solution. Or at least not for a solution that tries to press everything in a single stream-pipeline.

Comment: @Turing85 As I was reading the OP's question, I was thinkin the same thing.

Comment: Both `item.getValue().equals(Boolean.TRUE)`  and `item.getValue()` are prone to NPE if the `getValue` returns `Boolean`

Comment: You cannot know the size of a stream unless you terminate it as it's not a data structure. So even if you manage to combine that into a single pipeline (e.g. through `Opional`) - it would still look ugly (perhaps even worse). So I agree with @Turing85 that steams may not be the best option to use

Comment: This assumption _the idea of having to check if the size of the list is less than 2 to know that it has not found the 2 path of the first one_ does not seem to be correct: the _filtered_ list may have size over 2 but this does not guarantee that _all_ entries from the `allowedPath`  set are available in the list.

Comment: I don't like the idea either, I even think the cost and performance is absurd. But they want to implement the logic and unfortunately I am not yet experienced enough to be able to discuss it with my superiors (although I have tried without success).
Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider filtering and collecting matched items against *both*
path sets simultaneously and paying the cost of having
another (sometimes superfluous) list around.

Add the following `import` declarations:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
```

Assuming the unspecified `ItemObject` type is, more or less:

```
interface ItemObject
{
    String getPath();
    boolean getValue();
}
```

Implement `filterPath` as follows:

```
private static List<ItemObject> filterPath(
                final List<ItemObject> itemList)
{
    class PairCollector<T, U>
    {
        private final Predicate<T> primaryFilter;
        private final Predicate<T> secondaryFilter;
        private final Predicate<List<T>> selectFilter;
        private final List<T> primaryList;
        private final List<T> secondaryList;

        PairCollector(Function<Set<U>, Predicate<T>> pairFilter,
                    Predicate<List<T>> selectFilter,
                    Set<U> primarySet,
                    Set<U> secondarySet,
                    int listCapacity)
        {
            this.primaryFilter = pairFilter.apply(
                            primarySet);
            this.secondaryFilter = pairFilter.apply(
                            secondarySet);
            this.selectFilter = selectFilter;
            this.primaryList = new ArrayList<>(
                            listCapacity);
            this.secondaryList = new ArrayList<>(
                            listCapacity);
        }

        PairCollector<T, U> filter(T item)
        {
            if (primaryFilter.test(item))
                primaryList.add(item);

            if (selectFilter.test(primaryList)
                    && secondaryFilter.test(item))
                secondaryList.add(item);

            return this;
        }

        List<T> selectPrimaryElseSecondary()
        {
            return selectFilter.test(primaryList)
                ? secondaryList
                : primaryList;
        }
    }

    return Collections.unmodifiableList(itemList
        .stream()
        .reduce(new PairCollector<>((Set<String> paths) ->
                        (ItemObject item) ->
                                paths
                        .stream()
                        .anyMatch(path -> item
                                .getPath()
                                .contains(path)
                            && item.getValue()),
                    list -> list.size() < 2,
                    ALLOWED_PATH,
                    SECOND_ALLOWED_PATH,
                    itemList.size()),
            PairCollector::filter,
            (left, right) -> {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            })
        .selectPrimaryElseSecondary());
}
```

A variant implementation with bound-only-variables lambda
expressions. (`Item` occurs free in the predicate argument
of `anyMatch` in the above implementation.)

```
private static List<ItemObject> filterPath(
                final List<ItemObject> itemList)
{
    class PairCollector<T, U>
    {
        private final Predicate<Predicate<U>> primaryFilter;
        private final Predicate<Predicate<U>> secondaryFilter;
        private final Function<T, Predicate<U>> matcher;
        private final Predicate<List<T>> selectFilter;
        private final List<T> primaryList;
        private final List<T> secondaryList;

        PairCollector(Function<Set<U>, Predicate<Predicate<U>>>
                            pairFilter,
                Function<T, Predicate<U>> matcher,
                Predicate<List<T>> selectFilter,
                Set<U> primarySet,
                Set<U> secondarySet,
                int listCapacity)
        {
            this.primaryFilter = pairFilter.apply(
                            primarySet);
            this.secondaryFilter = pairFilter.apply(
                            secondarySet);
            this.matcher = matcher;
            this.selectFilter = selectFilter;
            this.primaryList = new ArrayList<>(
                            listCapacity);
            this.secondaryList = new ArrayList<>(
                            listCapacity);
        }

        PairCollector<T, U> filter(T item)
        {
            final Predicate<U> matcher_ = matcher.apply(item);

            if (primaryFilter.test(matcher_))
                primaryList.add(item);

            if (selectFilter.test(primaryList)
                    && secondaryFilter.test(matcher_))
                secondaryList.add(item);

            return this;
        }

        List<T> selectPrimaryElseSecondary()
        {
            return selectFilter.test(primaryList)
                ? secondaryList
                : primaryList;
        }
    }

    return Collections.unmodifiableList(itemList
        .stream()
        .reduce(new PairCollector<>(
                paths -> paths.stream()::anyMatch,
                (ItemObject item) ->
                    (String path) -> item
                        .getPath()
                        .contains(path)
                    && item.getValue(),
                list -> list.size() < 2,
                ALLOWED_PATH,
                SECOND_ALLOWED_PATH,
                itemList.size()),
            PairCollector::filter,
            (left, right) -> {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            })
        .selectPrimaryElseSecondary());
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Aliaksei! 

I still think there must be a better business logic than this, but I have no other choice and I must implement it.

I am very grateful for the help... I don't have much experience with lambdas, I am going to investigate more about this topic.

Comment: With the offered implementation, more work will be done  
and some of it eventually abandoned whenever the filtered  
list elements meet the quota of 2 elements or more and are  
all at the list end (i.e. the recently added elements).  
Maybe it is tolerable for short lists.

Comment: I would take a closer look at the origin of the list  
argument passed to `valid`.  Where does it come from?  
If this list is put together in the code I own and its use  
is exclusively tied to `valid`, can I get away with using  
another data structure instead, e.g. `java.util.PriorityQueue`?  
(Pay attention to its iterator/spliterator guarantees.)